# Android resources for different densities

Tags: android, resources, pixel

Ok so I know questions about resources for different densities have already been asked, however I ran into a problem, which is why this question is different. Ok so on the android developers website here http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html it's stated to use the scale of 1.0 for mdpi, 1.5 for hdpi, 2.0 for xhpdi, and so forth. But the problem is this scale appears to be wrong. If I make an image that is 480x800 for the nexus 1, it will take up the entire screen. If I divide this by 1.5 to get the mdpi version which is the baseline, I will get 320x533.34 approximately. Now lets try multiplying this by 2.0 to get xhdpi version. You will get 640x1066.68. In other words, on a nexus 4 with xdpi and resolution of 768x1280, the image will NOT take up the whole screen. The scaling is not accurate. So I made an image that takes up the whole screen of the nexus 1, then scaled it according the the scale given by the android developers, and for other screens the image will not take up the whole screen. I want a scale that will give me complete accuracy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, on a nexus 4 with xdpi and resolution of 768x1280, the image will NOT take up the whole screen

It is not supposed to. Density has nothing to do with screen size. I can have an `-xhdpi` screen that is one inch, one foot, one meter, one mile, or one parsec in diagonal length. Those screens would have drastically different *resolutions*, but the density would be the same.

Comment: But then my image will be different across screens.. I thought the whole point of having those different drawable folders was so that the image would appear to be the same size across all screens.

Comment: @user3843164: It is. Size is measured in *inches*, not *pixels*.

Comment: But I want my image to take up the whole screen on every screen... I mean there would be no point if it appeared differently on different screens.

Comment: @user3843164: "But I want my image to take up the whole screen on every screen" -- that is not possible. There are many different aspect ratios in use on Android devices, and one image has only one aspect ratio. This is no different than in windowed operating systems, where your window can be of an arbitrary size chosen by the user, as you cannot take up the whole window for those either.

Comment: But how do you make your gameplay be the same for all users? If the images are different sizes, the gameplay is heavily affected..

Comment: @user3843164: "But how do you make your gameplay be the same for all users?" -- I don't write games. I would imagine that game developers have a variety of techniques for dealing with this, such as having a couple of versions of the image in different aspect ratios that can be used to better fill the screen. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question to inquire about the various techniques that can be used, after you have used a search engine to see what has already been written on the subject.

Comment: Ok thanks! Just one more final question, and I already asked this before in my first comment but I wasn't satisfied with the answer, what's the point of having the different drawable folders if it doesn't really solve anything?

Comment: @user3843164: Just because it doesn't solve your specific problem does not mean that "it doesn't really solve anything". It does not solve the problem of having a full-screen background, because there are other pieces to that problem, such as aspect ratio. There are many other uses of images, such as icons, that are not full-screen backgrounds, where the primary variable is the density. You can read more about that in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).

Answer (score 1):

MDPI is 1.0 as you said, not 1.5. If you create an image that is 480x800 in the MDPI folder, it will be scaled up to 720x1200 on an HDPI device, or 960x1600 on an XHDPI device. You're never going to get an image which properly fits all screens -- there are just too many aspect ratios and resolutions to do that properly. Try to avoid that design philosophy altogether if possible (e.g. maybe have a nine-patch image in the center with a stretchable region on the edges), or set the image to scale and crop to fit (e.g. scaleType="centerCrop") and keep important parts of the image away from the sides of the screen to allow for some wiggle room.

Comment: Do you think that if I create scaled bitmaps and make them fit a certain percent of the screen(say if I want it to fill 20 percent horizontally I would multiply 0.2 * displaymetrics.widthPixels) that that would be a good way to do it? Because if ur making  a game you want all sprites to be the same across all screens as much as possible. And I was talking about generating 480x800 for hdpi, not mdpi. Which is why I divided by 1.5 because that would GET you the mdpi version because if u multiply the quotient by 1.5 again you will get 480x800.